# Discord.js | "user_id" has an "undefined" value

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Following the discord.js guide for creating a currency system. I'm getting this error: *WHERE parameter "user_id" has invalid "undefined" value*

I can run my *!balance* command fine and I'm getting currency per message. This is for the *!inventory* command. My code:

**index.js**

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
     const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();    
    
    if (command === 'balance') {
        const target = message.author;
    
        return message.reply(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}!`);
    }
    
    if (command == "inventory") {
        const target = message.author;
        const user = await Users.findOne({where: {user_id: target.id}});
        const items = await user.getItems();
    
        if (!items.length) return message.reply(`${target.tag} has nothing!`);
    
        return message.reply(`${target.tag} currently has ${items.map(i => `${i.amount} ${i.item.name}`).join(' , ')}`);
            }

});
```

**Users.js**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
     return sequelize.define('users', {         
        user_id: {             
            type: DataTypes.STRING,             
            primaryKey: true,         
        },      
        balance: {             
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,             
            defaultValue: 0,             
            allowNull: false,         
        },     
    }, {         
    timestamps: false,     
    }); 
};
```

I made sure to run the *dbInit.js* file.

I'm a bit lost on what to try, honestly. This is my first time working with Discord.js; I expected to see the user inventory, but it seems like the user_id is undefined and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: `target` is already a user, did you mean `where: { user_id: target.id }`?

Comment: I did! I changed it, though it's still broken with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the WHERE-clause in the main code, but the WHERE-clause within the code of getItems().

I managed to find a solution here:
https://github.com/discordjs/guide/discussions/1085

It relates to the final code published on github by the creators of the guide. I don't know why it's different than in the guide, but it is:
https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/sequelize/currency/14/dbObjects.js